# linux ubuntu c++ .h and .cpp file

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have a my.h file:

```
#ifndef __MY__
#define __MY__

#include <string>
#include <time.h>

class S
{
    public: S();
    std::string myname;
};

#endif
```

my.cpp

```
#include "my.h";

#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

S::S()
{
    // .. code
}
```

I want to create an so file. There is no error when creating it. But when I compile the .h file it says: string:No such file or directory. If I pus string.h instead of string I have the error: expected '=',',',';','asm', before S (at class S) in my.h.
In the .cpp file (if i change the string with string.h) i have after i compile error: string in namespace std does not name a type. WHERE AM I WRONG?

Comment: What is your compile command line? And BTW, names like `__MY__` are not allowed to be created in user-written code.

Comment: Also it would be better to remove semicolon in first line of `my.cpp`

Comment: i am using geany code. i give build

Comment: In test.cpp I am calling the .so file: void* handle = dlopen("/home/path/test.so", RTLD_NOW);

 if(!handle)0
 {
  cout<<"not found"<<endl;
  return 0;
 }                                  I GET NOT FOUND AS RESULT. WHY? THE PATH IS CORRECT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, it seems that you come from java because when you typed:

```
class S
{
  public: S();
  std::string myname;
};
```

I guess you actually meant:

```
class S
{
  public:

    S();

  private:

    std::string myname;
};
```

In the `.cpp` file, you typed `s` instead of `S`: note that C++ is case-sensitive regarding classes names.

Also, regarding your problem, I suspect you are currently using a `C` compiler and not a `C++` compiler. Without knowing the used command-line, I can't say much more on that.

Comment: Thx for user answer. Why do i receive in cpp the error: my.h string in namespace std does not name a type?

Comment: i am working in the Geany program. I just gave build from the menu.

Comment: What is your compilation command-line ? I don't know what Geany is.

Comment: with g++ my.cpp -o my i have errors: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

class S
{
public: S();
std::string myname;
};

#endif



#include "my.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

S::S()
{
    //code
}
```